# Custom adapter in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout, listadapter

I try to do some calendar. I do it as **GridView** with custom adapter.
How in adapter combine 2 **TextView**(date and text) and icons (red circle) ?

[(screen for example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lt9t.png)

Comment: Could you add any of the code from your custom adapter or XML for your attempts as the layout of each item in the `GridView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must create a layout(with an `ImageView` for the icon and 2 `TextViews`) for each item and inflate the layout into a view in the `getView()` method of your `adapter`. Something like

```
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if(convertView == null) { // recycled view is null so create it.
          convertView = View.inflate(context, R.id.layout, parent);
     }
     ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
     TextView tv1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
     ...
}
```

Comment: view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file, null);  rather than convertView = View.inflate(context, R.id.layout, parent);